# Pass variable to html template in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, nodemailer

I want to send email with nodemailer using html template. In that template I need to inject some dynamically some variables and I really can't do that. My code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: mailConfig.host,
    secure: mailConfig.secure,
    port: mailConfig.port,
    auth: {
        user: mailConfig.auth.user,
        pass: mailConfig.auth.pass
    }
}));
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'my@email.com',
    to : 'some@email.com',
    subject : 'test subject',
    html : { path: 'app/public/pages/emailWithPDF.html' }
};
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        callback(error);
    }
});
```

Let's say I want in emailWithPDF.html something like this:

```
Hello {{username}}!
```

I've found some examples, where was smth like this:

```
...
html: '<p>Hello {{username}}</p>'
...
```

but I want it in separate html file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

What you can do is read the HTML file using `fs` module in node and then replace the elements that you want changed in the html string using `handlebars`

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');

var readHTMLFile = function(path, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
           callback(err);                 
        }
        else {
            callback(null, html);
        }
    });
};

smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: mailConfig.host,
    secure: mailConfig.secure,
    port: mailConfig.port,
    auth: {
        user: mailConfig.auth.user,
        pass: mailConfig.auth.pass
    }
}));

readHTMLFile(__dirname + 'app/public/pages/emailWithPDF.html', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
       console.log('error reading file', err);
       return;
    }
    var template = handlebars.compile(html);
    var replacements = {
         username: "John Doe"
    };
    var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'my@email.com',
        to : 'some@email.com',
        subject : 'test subject',
        html : htmlToSend
     };
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any another way for the same like we do in case of `.pug` file, we just pass object to map variable

Comment: Does this supports inline CSS styling?

Comment: Yes it does, you can add the css styling to your html page

Comment: Thanks, @AnanthPai, posted answer is really helpful. Initially, I was very much confused about dynamic email templates with handlebars, express-handlebars, etc. now having clear things.

Comment: how i can use or print variable in view file ?

Comment: @AnanthPai, what is the callback in smtpTransport.sendMail function. It is throwing error of "callback is not defined"

Comment: @JaynaTanawala You can remove `callback(error);`. You don't need it. I have updated my code, it was an error in the code.

Answer (score 23):

I use it in all my projects. more clean and up to date and understandable. callback hell doesn't exist.
**sendMail.ts** The html file reads with handlebar, puts the relevant variables into the contents, and sends.

```js
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import * as handlebars from 'handlebars';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

export async function sendEmail(email: string, subject: string, url: string) {
  const __dirname = path.resolve();
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../emails/password-reset.html');
  const source = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').toString();
  const template = handlebars.compile(source);
  const replacements = {
    username: "Umut YEREBAKMAZ"
  };
  const htmlToSend = template(replacements);
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: 2525, // 587
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: "fg7f6g7g67",
      pass: "asds7ds7d6"
    }
  });
  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"noreply@yourdomain.com" <noreply@yourdomain.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    text: url,
    html: htmlToSend
  };
  const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", "https://mailtrap.io/inboxes/test/messages/");

}
```

Comment: Can you use local images in the HTML template this way? Tried using one but it wouldn't load. Using URLs does work of course.

Comment: You can use it if you give absolute paths of the files on the server.
for example: https://yourdomain.com/images/logo.png you can use it like traditional html.

They explained a different way in the document on the offical site.
https://community.nodemailer.com/using-embedded-images/

I still find my way easier and more flexible. I prepare my html template first and then I include it in the work.

Comment: I did the same. But my CSS is not getting linked with html. What might be the reason ?

Comment: If you are going to use css for emails, make sure to use inline style.

Comment: **2023** and this one is working during my testing. Though, I need to add `const __dirname = path.resolve();` to fix the `__dirname not define` issue in my case. Clean codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

String **replace** isn't a good idea because you'll have to restore old strings or create a backup file to be able to change them another time, also it won't be asynchrone and it will cause a problem in every way!
you can do it **much easier** and **more cleaner**:

just go to your **mail options** and add **context** with your variables:

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'nginx-iwnl@gmail.com',
  to: 'username@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending email',
  template: 'yourTemplate',
  context: {                  // <=
    username: username,
    whatever: variable
  }
};
```

**next thing** to do is openning your html file and call your variables like:

{{username}}

Comment: tried but not working for me, any additional setting? @larachiwnl

Answer (score 8):

Create one file `emailTemplates.js` there yo can store each template as a function

emailTemplates.js

```
const newsLetterEmail = (clientName) => `<p>Hi ${clientName}, here you have today news.</p>`
const welcomeEmail = (clientName, username) => `<p>Welcome ${clientName}, your username is ${username}.</p>`

export {newsLetterEmail, welcomeEmail}
```

Then in the controllers call any templateFunction and store in output varaible

controller.js

```
import {welcomeEmail} from './emailTeamplates.js'

const registerUser = async(req, res) => {
    const {name, usename, email} = req.body
    // User register code....
    const output = welcomeEmail(name, username)

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Welcome" <welcome@welcome.com>',
        to: 'client@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Welcome email!',
        text: 'Hello World',
        html: output,
    }
```

Comment: the best answer

Comment: The best ever, simple and easy thanks Cesar

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Nodemailer 2.0.0 or higher, check this documentation:
https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/ There they explain how to make use of external rendering with templates like that:

```
// external renderer
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var send = transporter.templateSender(new EmailTemplate('template/directory'));
```

They also give this example:

```
// create template based sender function
// assumes text.{ext} and html.{ext} in template/directory
var sendPwdReminder = transporter.templateSender(new EmailTemplate('template/directory'), {
    from: 'sender@example.com',
});
```

where you see how to pass variables.

You will need the `email-templates` module: https://github.com/crocodilejs/node-email-templates and a template engine of your choice.

Also in the documentation of `email-templates` you'll find how to make your file structure in order that your templates can be found:

> html.{{ext}} (required) - for html format of email
>
> text.{{ext}} (optional) - for text format of email style.
>
> {{ext}}(optional) - styles for html format subject.
>
> {{ext}}(optional) - for subject of email
>
> See supported template engines for possible template engine extensions (e.g. .ejs, .jade, .nunjucks) to use for the value of {{ext}} above.
>
> You may prefix any file name with anything you like to help you identify the files more easily in your IDE. The only requirement is that the filename contains html., text., style., and subject. respectively.

Comment: Is there any another way for the same like we do in case of .pug file, we just pass object to map variable

Answer (score 4):

**For those using pug as templating engine**

Just a quick way to render a template in a separate file using pug's render function:

```
// function to send an e-mail. Assumes you've got nodemailer and pug templating engine installed. 
// transporter object relates to nodemailer, see nodemailer docs for details
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const pug = require('pug');
function send_some_mail(iterable){
var message = {
  from: 'from@example.com',
  to: 'to@example.com',
  subject: 'Message title',
  html: pug.renderFile(__dirname + 'path_to_template.pug', {iterable: iterable})
};
transporter.sendMail(message, function(err, info){...})
}

// template.pug
each item in iterable
li
  p #{item.name}
```

See https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html for further details. Note that this will cause template re-compilation every time a message is sent. That is fine for occasional e-mail deliveries. If you send tons of e-mails, you can cache the compiled template to work around that. Check out pug docs for that set up if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **Web Request** to build an html template using `handlebars` or any other engine.

### Create a template

First you must create an html template for the email body. In this example I used a handlebars `hbs` file.

[image]

Do your design stuff with html and add the variables that you will need in the message:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome Email Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">Hi {{data.name}}</p>
    </body>
   </html>
```

### Create a template request

You must create the access to this view. Then a request is created where we can send the template name as an url parameter to make the request parameterizable for other templates.

```
const web = express.Router()

web.post('/template/email/:template', function(req, res) {
  res.render(`templates/email/${req.params.template}`, {
    data: req.body        
  })
})
```

### Mail function

Finally you can send the email after making the request to the template. You can use a function like the following:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const request = require("request")

function sendEmail(toEmail, subject, templateFile) {
    var options = {
        uri: `http://localhost:3000/template/email/${templateFile}`,
        method: 'POST',
        json: { name: "Jon Snow" } // All the information that needs to be sent
    };  
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) console.log(error)
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: mailConfig.host,
            port: mailConfig.port,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: mailConfig.account,
                pass: mailConfig.password
            }
        })
        var mailOptions = {
            from: mailConfig.account,
            to: toEmail,
            subject: subject,
            html: body
        }       
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) console.log(error)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` for emails?... It's a bit longer than that.

Comment: any examples links to this implementation codebox or codepen something to view the complete flow in action.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without templates.

Try changing it to this:

```
`Hello ${username}!`
```

Make sure that these are not inverted commas but back ticks.

Comment: This will come out as text now html.

Comment: This could be dangerous because the text will not be HTML-encoded

Answer (score 2):

There is one easy way to insert variable inside html in nodemailer.

```
    html:"<p>Your message "+variable1+".Message continueous "+variable 2+"</p>"
```

Comment: Make sure  that you don't put a space in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async/await syntax or promises and avoid using callbacks, like I did here, using async/await:

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const relativeTemplatePath = "../../html/reset-pw-email-template.html";

function sendEmail(){
    const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, relativeTemplatePath);
    const templateFile = await fs.readFile(templatePath, 'utf-8');
    const template = handlebars.compile(templateFile);
    const replacements = {
        username:""
    };
    const finalHtml = template(replacements);
    const mailOptions = {
       from: "",
       to: "",
       subject: "",
       html: finalHtml,
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For pug template: `#{}` way might not well supported.

```
- var url = thisIsTheVariable;
a(href='/' + url) Link
```

Doc is [here](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, i tried making a simple as possible so if something more is needed like extra error checking you can add

```
import fs from 'fs';

import Handlebars from 'handlebars';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: 'anjali.pollich@ethereal.email',
    pass: 'qZjeVE5F3WQWwdBmek',
  },
});

const readFileSync = (path: string) => {
  return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + path, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
};

export const registerMail = async (user) => {
  const template = Handlebars.compile(readFileSync('/test.html'));

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Info" <info@gmail.com>',
    to: 'test@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Validate your email address',
    html: template({ username: user.name }),
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
};
```