# NodeJS and express How to send variables with the template when sending emails using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am using `nodemailer` to send emails for users on registration. The function is as following:

```
const setAndSendMsg = (recipients, users, subject, template) => {
    const htmlFile = checkTemplate(template)
    const message = {
        from: mailServer.mailerObj.auth.user,
        bcc: recipients,
        subject: subject,
        // html: `<div><b>Hello</b></div>`,
        html: htmlFile,       
        context: {
            user: 'test'
        }
    }

    transport.sendMail(message, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            return data
        }
    })
}
```

`checkTemplate` return the required template:

```
const checkTemplate = (template) => {
    return fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `../email-templates/${template}.html`), 'utf-8').toString()
}
```

The template contains:

```
<div>
    Dear {{user}},
    <br/>
    <div>
        Welcome to our platform, please click on the link below to activate your account:
        
    </div>
</div>
```

The email is well received to all recipients as follows:

Dear {{user}}, ...

without `test` being displayed in place of `{{user}}`

I used the script from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489229/pass-variable-to-html-template-in-nodemailer) on stackoverflow but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the template engine you are using?

Comment: @Bibek normal html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your config, you're defining your template as static html, and therefore no variables are being evaluated there, if you go to the templating documentation of node-mailer [here](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/), you'll find that is not supported anymore, and instead they send you [here](https://email-templates.js.org/#/). My suggestion would be to follow the official documentation, they offer good examples there.

Other way would be to manually render the template into a static html and set it to the mailer, that's if you don't want to install another package, but `email-templates` does this for you :)

Hope this helps.

Cheers :)